# Search for an entry - in a Database ( without specifying a Column name/Table name)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it possible to search for an entry in a whole database without specifying which table and in which column ? 
And get the Table name that contains the entry we searched , like

```
SELECT (Table name ? )FROM (Database - not Table) WHERE ( unknown column ?) = 'our value';
```

I mean the result should be the Table name itself.

Comment: nothing like that built into SQL... what you describe sounds more like a document store is much better suited than any SQL DB.

Comment: You could use `mysql_list_tables` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php) to get a list of all tables. Then iterate through them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for as I know there is nothing built-into MySQL that accomplishes this, however there is an alternative. This is not a very efficient approach, but if you must do this there is a way!

http://code.google.com/p/anywhereindb/