# How to search for a value in Mysql all tables without specifying the table name and column name?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT @sqlText = @sqlText + ' SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + CHAR(13) FROM sys.tables
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database

Comment: See the link below. This may help you. [here] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950408/search-for-an-entry-in-a-database-without-specifying-a-column-name-table-nam

Answer (score 0):

[image]If you are using phpmyadmin do the following steps:
1) select the database
2) Select search from the top links
3) Now you will get text box to enter what to search
4) Select the table in which you want to search. 
It will search whole database get the result

Answer (score -1):

You can't search like that. You can write a query as

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE MATCH(`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) AGAINST ('$searchword')
```